# UIAlertView Dismissed Covers Another View

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I'm trying to show a Facebook post to wall window when the user dismisses a UIAlertView, I.E., it is showing the window inside the clickedButtonAtIndex delegate method called when the person taps on OK. WHat appears to happen is the UIAlertView dismisses itself and puts the original view (the main application view) to the front, effectively covering the new Facebook popup that has just been shown.

Anybody know how to do this?

Thanks,

Kidovate (Christian Stewart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why UIAlertView behaves that way, but I guess you can show Facebook Window after some delay with **performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:** inside clickedButtonAtIndex method.